# Reputation cut down by 100

Tags: discussion, reputation

I see that my reputation has become 949 from 1049 even though I find no notification of downvotes anywhere. This happened around 5 mins ago.

Can someone help me with why this has happened?

Comment: How long has it been at 1049? Did that just happen today?

Comment: It was on 1049. It's weird. It had been @ 1049 since 8-10 hours and I had even unlocked name plate badge.

Comment: Do you have "Show Removed Posts" at the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/users/5482966/mathews-mathai?tab=reputation checked?  If not, check it.  If you lost 100 rep due to a deleted post (or series of deleted posts), it should show up when you check that box

Comment: I can't see anything, but maybe a full reputation audit will show you some details.  While logged in, visit https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: @KevinB With a bit of manuvering on the reputation graph on the top of the OP's activity tab, I _am_ hitting a "1049" spot, so it does appear they _have_ hit 1049.

Comment: I had recently deleted a post on meta. Because it was marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Nothing you do on Meta affects your reputation. The only way it could is by driving people to your main profile and drawing attention to your posts there, but that's an indirect effect.

Comment: Do the same, but on your main profile.

Comment: If your rep immediately dropped by 100 points and we don't see a "voting reversed" or "user removed" record in your rep, I suspect one of a couple things: A really highly voted post (or two) of yours was (or were) deleted, which you'd see via psubee2003's suggestion, or a post of yours was flagged and deleted as spam/offensive, which carries an automatic 100 rep penalty. If the latter, I think a mod would have to tell us.

Comment: @Kendra Why doesn't it show up in the notification?

Comment: I doubt the devs wanted to notify people, "Hey, you royally screwed up, so we're docking you 100 rep." But honestly, I don't know why. That's a design decision on the dev's part, and I can only make guesses at the moment as I don't know if that's been asked before.

Comment: @ryanyuyu -- 2016-03-14 rep +34   = 1005      
 1  36000442 (15)
 1  35988688 (15)
 2  36008409 (10)
 16 36009044 (2)
 4  36008606 (-100)
 16 36011717 (2)
-- 2016-03-15 rep -56   = 949

Comment: @Kendra I see a -100 there but I have no clue why.

Comment: Then I would hazard a guess it's one of the flags, but I don't have access to the information to tell you for sure if that's the case, or which flag, or what have you. You'll need a mod for that. I'm sure one will pop in shortly and help you sort this out.

Comment: @MathewsMathai according to the [MSE how to audit my reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation), that code of 4 for post 36008606 is an "offensive" flag.

Comment: @Kendra How does the mod work? I am new to it. I am afraid I'll be able to handle it efficiently when it pops in.

Comment: @MathewsMathai she means a diamond moderator.  Flag a post with a custom reason.  Or just wait since many of them visit meta.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I would like to know which comment turned out to be offensive. I didn't insult anyone though. Neither made any rude comments. Waiting for the mod thing.

Comment: Looks like a spam flag was used/approved by the community on a joke answer. *"$9999 will be the minimum cost. You could ask Mr.Google if you want more details."*

Comment: Oh. That one. Is that offensive though?

Comment: eh, no, but seem as though several people decided to flag it. I doubt it even made it to a moderator since it was handled by **Community**

Comment: @KevinB Is there a way by which I could speak against it?..Maybe point it out to a moderator and get the lost repo back?

Comment: I see what happened. The question was posted by a spam bot, the other answers also, and your answer got thrown out with the water as also spam.

Comment: @KevinB Wait..What does that mean?..It was flagged by bots?

Comment: No... the question and the other answers appear to have been posted by bots. :)

Comment: @KevinB That means I deserve my repo back. Is there a way out. A 100 is too big for me.

Comment: Just wait for a mod to come along

Comment: @MathewsMathai if nothing else, it might be an expensive lesson that joke answers are really not a smart idea, even on a post that is obviously spam.

Comment: Okay. I see. The mod seems to be powerful. mod-respect++
Why are they called mod though? Anyway, should I flag this for a moderator's attention?

Comment: mod is short for "Moderator", they're elected volunteers who moderate the community they were elected by.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes. Learnt a lesson. Didn't even know that it was a spam and the bot deserved it maybe.

Comment: _"Why are they called mod though?"_ "Mod" is short for "Moderator." It comes from the first three letters of the longer word. It's a very common way to shorten "moderator" on here and various forums on the internet. As for flagging this question, I wouldn't bother. One of them will come across this post soon enough without the flag. Several of them browse meta often.

Comment: @Kendra Got it. Should I flag this post for mod's attention so that I receive some justice soon enough?

Comment: I actually edited my comment to address that, but you may not have seen it before posting yours. :) Several of the mods browse meta, so one of them will see this soon enough without it being flagged. I wouldn't worry about it. One of them may already be looking into it and just hasn't said anything while they work. Otherwise, one of them will pop in soon enough. Just be patient.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot guys. Didn't expect such an amazing response. Feeling good @SO.

Comment: I got it back. Thanks to the mod and the other amazing people here who helped me in this. Should I be deleting this post now?

Comment: @KevinB The mod saved me.

Comment: You'll find you can't delete questions that have upvoted answers. meagar spent time answering this and it would be unfair to delete his answer which is what would happen if we allowed you to delete the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson I received the answer after making that comment. :)

Answer (score 250, accepted):

I'm the one responsible for your loss of reputation. I originally came across [this now deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36008512/229044) to which you responded with a useless, snarky answer:

> $9999 will be the minimum cost. You could ask Mr.Google if you want more details.

I flagged your answer as "rude", which it was. If you find questions on this site asked by new users, which you believe are not appropriate for Stack Overflow, vote to close them or leave a **constructive** comment. Responding with snarky sarcastic answers is not welcome here.

Unfortunately, "rude" flags from moderators carry an instant 100 point reputation loss, which **I felt was justified in this case**. At 1000 reputation, you should know better than to treat bad questions by new users as an opportunity to dog pile sarcastic answers.

That said, I flagged your answer *before* digging a little deeper into the question and the other answers and discovering that all three of the other participants were spammers sharing an IP address. So, **in this case**, your snark was pretty harmless. But had this been a real new user to the site asking an honest question, your answer would have been extremely off-putting.

After talking about it with other moderators, they decided that the 100 point loss of reputation was a little steep, and restored it.

Comment: I think OP should get a notification for that. A reputation penalty without an explanation is useless. How will someone know he's doing something bad?

Comment: shouldn't there be a big red warning telling you if one of your posts gets offensive or spam deleted?

Comment: Wait, sarcastic rude comments carry no penalty, but sarcastic rude *answers* carry a -100 rep payload? Is that really fair?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi IIRC Rude comments can get you site banned for repedeatly making them.

Comment: If that answer was considered as rude, I should be facing that cut down of 100 because I did it without knowing that it was spam. Punish me since I deserve it. I really didn't know that it would be considered as rude. Sorry.

Comment: @Magish, you mean suspended? I don't think we can actually ban anyone completely.

Comment: @MathewsMathai Yes, I should have notified you via mod message or comment. Sorry for that lapse on my part. As I said, after I flagged your answer I dug deeper into the thread and wound up burning some time confirming that the other accounts were spammers and then nuking them, after which I had to go to work. I only became aware of this question when another moderator pinged me in chat.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Ah, man, there are too many "Ma" initials in here.

Comment: Sorry for that rude answer.

Comment: @MathewsMathai I'm not going to take away the rep, and I apologize for the confusion it caused in the first place. In retrospect, a comment or mod message warning you would have been more appropriate, and I'm glad we got things sorted out with no loss of reputation to your account. I will be more judicious with my use of "rude" flags in the future. Now, I actually have to get back to work :)

Comment: Okay. And I will be more careful with funny answers. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Personally think the rude flag was justified, didn't expect you to collapse so easily. If anything it teaches the OP a valuable lesson, don't do it again or face the consequence.

Comment: @Lankymart I admit I tend to be a little bit blind to what 100 reputation means to some users. It's an insignificant amount for me, but for the user in question it is 10% of their total reputation. That seems like a harsh punishment for a first offence. Regardless of whether the reputation is restored, I think the lesson is well learned and the offence will not be repeated, so punitively taking away the reputation isn't really a constructive thing to do.

Comment: You're a bigger person then me... *(and they call me lanky!)*

Comment: @MarounMaroun - The 100-point penalty is something of an artifact from the older days of the site. It was used to quickly reduce the permissions of an identified spammer or troll while we dealt with the account, but we have far better tools and means of dealing with this now. Almost all accounts subject to this penalty are about to be destroyed, so it's not often that a legitimate user gets hit by this.

Comment: *Waits for someone to add a "try freethemes" answer here*

Comment: *Bans @bhargavrao for being a freethemes spammer*

Comment: I love that one answer that starts by *scolding* Mathews Mathai before reiterating the spam message.  Can you feel the burn?

Comment: Just a clarification, you said `"rude" flags from moderators carry an instant 100 point reputation loss`, but actually [if any post gets six spam or offensive flags from regular users, a 100 points reputation loss is incurred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/288751), when mods cast these flags, it is as if that mod was actually six normal people. So yes, a rude flag from a mod carries a 100 point reputation loss, but that is no different from six people flagging as spam or offensive.

Comment: It seems a little far fetched to call that answer useless and rude/offensive. Slightly sarcastic and lacking in explanatory details, but I think a downvote would have sufficed. For something to be offensive, to most people it would have to be a lot worse than simply suggesting that someone search on Google (e.g. perhaps calling the OP stupid, or involving racism, etc.). For it to be useless it would have to provide no information at all, whereas this one appeared to provide something (albeit I have no access to the question, so that is an assumption on my part).

Comment: @JBentley:  If I had seen that answer in a legitimate Q/A, I would have flagged it as offensive.  Sure, it's not *very* rude, but the point is that it served no other purpose *but* to be rude.  ("Just Google it" is never helpful, and rarely meant to be.)

Comment: The answer as quoted above was not "just google it" - it appears to be a small bit of information followed by an (arguably snarky) suggestion to consult a search engine *" if you want more details"*.  If someone is offended by that then perhaps they ought to *try freethemes*?

Comment: @AlanMoore but it didn't *only* suggest searching Google and even if it did that would fulfil only the "useless" criterion. As much as Google search suggestions are against the spirit of SO and are disliked, that doesn't make them offensive in a way that most ordinary people get offended. Rude flags should be reserved for genuinely offensive cases and not used as a more severe form of downvote for posts that people dislike a lot.

Comment: @AlanMoore [This help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) Gives several good examples of when to use the flag. They are things like name calling, racism, harassment, bullying etc.

Comment: @billynoah: The question was, "Is any body having knowledge about website templates i need to create a own website at free of cost". The answer was, "$9999 will be the minimum cost. You could ask Mr.Google if you want more details." So, both parts of the answer were just snark, with no sincere information.

Comment: lol.  well yeah, that does put things in perspective.  i guess it was snark all around then.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Actually there are no *notifications* for loss of rep, because, for some reason, SO devs don't think you ought to be notified of negative changes. Of course, this is foolish; we need to be notified of *every* change to our standing, positive, neutral, or negative. Either way, I do agree that we should be notified *somewhere* of the reputation loss. If nothing else, when viewing our own reputation graph on the profile page, it should show a private "-100 - post deleted as rude/offensive" and link you to it.

Comment: I *severely* disagree with reputation penalties, while the answer was garbage, why didn't you just issue a warning, or some answer ban?

Comment: All users are equal, but some users are more equal than others.

Comment: at least you didn't charge *him* $10K for answering *his* question...

Comment: I am utterly mystified by any of you who think that answer wasn't profoundly useless and pure snark.  Those who are suggesting there was some intrinsic value to "$9999 will be the minimum cost. You could ask Mr.Google if you want more details." -- please inform me what the value was; I will pay $9999 to find out.

Comment: @SterlingArcher An answer ban? That is drastically more punishing than a reputation loss.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, to your first comment, requesting a feature request: I just posted [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319271/feature-added-to-show-that-your-answer-has-been-marked-as-rude-or-offensive) question regarding the notification. I hope that is the exact implementation you wanted. Thanks for first ringing the idea in my mind, about a notification.

Comment: That's quite harsh. Personally, a shower of community downvotes on the answer would have a) highlighted to the user that the answer was unfair b) demystified the penalty for the affected user and c) would probably have been better than a loss in points anyway.

Comment: Would that be considered as rude if it was a comment?...Only asking.

Comment: Does a rude, non-answer really meet the criteria of: "The Offensive flag is meant to be used only in extreme cases, like hate speech, abuse against people, or abuse of the system."? [source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/167315).

Comment: @MathewsMathai I'm not sure if it would be flagged as offensive if it was a comment, but it would certainly be flagged as "not constructive" (which does not have the 100 point penalty).