# Feature added to show that your answer has been marked as rude or offensive

Tags: feature-request, rude-or-abusive

I had recently come across [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319021/reputation-cut-down-by-100?cb=1) meta question. In this case, the user didn't know why the reputation was deducted. I request a feature to be added to show tell why the reputation was deducted. So this would inform the user that he / she has a post which was marked rude  or offensive by a moderator, or by 6 users. It would look like (I'm not a pinta expert. The original would look very different and clear):

[image]

But also include the answer or question, which was marked rude or offensive:

[image]

Everything in blue are links. The first one the link to answer or question, and the second one to inform users who are not understanding why the reputation was deducted.

I hope this can also be done for spam. Same thing, but instead of showing the "Rude or Offensive" message, show "Spam".

This will help users to identify why the reputation was deducted.

Also, please post your opinions. They will help implement the actual feature.

**NOTE:** This feature isn't implemented yet, and the images I have posted are not the actuals. They have just been edited, and added how the message would look.

**EDIT:** To make the question clearer, note that this message will only be visible to the user who got the penalty. Not to anyone else. This will appear in the reputation tab.

Comment: The downvoter likely disagrees with this idea, that's how meta voting works.

Comment: @RobertLongson: thanks for letting me know that. But do you have any idea why the downvoter disagrees with the idea? As per your opinion, is there something wrong in this proposal?

Comment: "This feature isn't implemented yet" It's not? Or is this only visible to moderators and not to the user looking at their own rep history?

Comment: @BoltClock, I don't know about moderators, but I want this to be visible to the user. Like when you're serial voted, and the reputation is reversed, you see a message similar to this in the reputation tab. So it would be good if this can be implemented in the same way, and shown in the reputation tab.

Comment: @BoltClock, also, this isn't currently visible to the user. That is why there was confusion on the meta post I've linked.

Comment: @Ashish Note that in the vast majority of cases where this occurs the account generally ends up deleted anyway. In cases where it's desirable to keep the account around, it often makes sense to mod message the user to find out what's going on anyway. I'm neither yay/nay on this as a feature but it'd have to be shown to that user only - having a spam/offensive entry publicly available in your rep. history will be a red flag and a hindrance in moving forward. Note that the user-removed entry is often outside of the user's control (and explained as such) so isn't quite such a red flag.

Comment: @Jon Clements: That's precisely what they're asking. For it to be shown to the user owning the post. The fact that most accounts that get hit with this get deleted is irrelevant - otherwise why would the rep penalty be there at all?

Comment: @BoltClock historical reasons when the tooling to deal with accounts was different... it was designed to drop the rep of users (most likely new users) to something that removed enough privs to reduce any other disruptive/undesirable actions they could take (commenting/voting etc...)

Comment: @JonClements, I mean to say that this will be only visible to the user itself. I'll edit my question. Also you cannot say that the account gets deleted as an excuse. The author of the linked question got the penalty, and the account isn't deleted. The user has made a lot of contributions. If this feature is implemented, it will remove a lot of confusions. Also, you're saying that you normally mod message the user, but that didn't happen in the case of the linked question. Exceptions happen, and it is not possible to stop exceptions. Implementing this feature will make the system foolproof.

Comment: Seems already [tag:status-completed] :)

Comment: @AndrewT, yup. I thought this wasn't implemented as in the question I linked, the OP always answered no when asked something like "Did you see some message in the reputation tab" in comments. My bad :-(

Comment: Your images made me try to clean my notebook screen.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: lol. I already put a warning in brackets _"The original would look very different and **clear**"_ (emphasis mine)

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ: You can use Inspect in Chrome or FireBug in Firefox to edit the HTML directly and cleanly =D

Comment: @justhalf, I would've love to do that, but the problem is that I don't even know `HTML` properly. Just know the basic elements like `<html>`. And that is not `HTML`. It is an image, which I modified using Pinta (the linux version of Paint).

Comment: Ah I see. But at any case, the Inspect tool is actually user-friendly in the sense that you can just modify the relevant text =)

Comment: A feature-request with title saying "Feature added" is a bit confusing. I would say "Add feature" instead.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged with the existing [offensive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/offensive) tag instead of a new rude-or-offensive tag?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This feature already exists and is already visible to moderators as well as the owner of the affected post. Just as with any other rep changes on deleted posts, it's likely the other user didn't enable "show removed posts" in their rep history, which would explain why they missed it.

Here's a screenshot for proof. Also, test accounts come in very handy (though this one belongs to Jon — obviously I would *never* stoop to that level myself, even with a sock puppet...):

[image]

Comment: Ugg... Where did that old gravatar go?